# Not getting data returns from DB in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am having an issue where I can not get any data returned if I do a `$this->Model->find('all')` if I use a more specific search for data such as `$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Model.column LIKE' => $search))` I can get some values returned for that search but not all that are able to be searched. Example if I do: `$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Model.column LIKE' => 1))` I get a return of all of the rows that contain the specified column with a value of one. If I change it to 2 then I will get a null return even though there are `Model.column` columns with 2 for the value. This is really making me go insane at the moment since I have built quite a few sites on cake and MySQL is returning no errors in the log. Here is the code I am working with as well as my db setup:

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_cleps_subjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `credits` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `course` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `extract` text NOT NULL,
  `factsheet` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `study_guide` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;
```

Model:

```
class ClepsSubject extends AppModel {

}
```

Controller:

```
class ClepsController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('ClepsSubject');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('return', $this->ClepsSubject->find('all'));
    }

}
```

Controller View:

```
<?php debug($return); ?>
```

Like I said im banging my head against the wall on this one any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the sql query that was generated by Cake to retrieve your data

Comment: As said above, we need the generated sql query by Cake. My guess is that you're using a LIKE query with integer, and that Cake is trying to convert your integer to string first, because it doesn;t make much sense using LIKE with an integer

Answer (score -1):

Try fetch_array function for php http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Can you improve what you are trying to suggest?

Comment: I was able to solve this by creating a new table by copying a separate table over and importing the values. This leads me to believe that there was an error in MySQL while creating the table and that it was something that MySQL and CakePHP did not receive and error from. I am going through everything and trying to pinpoint this issue so that I can leave the answer here for anyone who may run into similar issues.